# Performing partial backup in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have more separate independent structures in the database. I need to do a backup for each of these structures separately and not to do a full backup of everything.

I am interested is there a way to do a backup of some specific graph part. I checked what backup strategies there are in the neo4j documentation. There are incremental backup and full backup, but I could not find the possibility to extract and backup only some part of the graph or maybe some independent graph structure in the database. 
Ideal would be to define cypher query and to get the result like that. For example in most relational databases it is possible to extract/backup separate table or dataset (depending on database). So that is something I am looking to do in neo4j too. Define node label and then do a backup or by some other criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **experimental** `dump` command along with the shell :

Example: `dumping the user nodes` to a `users.cypher` file that will contain all the cypher statements for recreating the users later :

```
./bin/neo4j-shell -c 'dump MATCH (n:User) RETURN n;' > users.cypher
```

Related info in the documentation : http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/shell-commands.html#_dumping_the_database_or_cypher_statement_results

Comment: Thank you. I found that tool today. That is exactly what I need.